# Using Microsoft Teams on Gnome Wayland - Not able to screen share

Tags: arch-linux, microsoft-teams

currently i'm using Manjaro with Gnome and the wayland session manager.

`5.15.68-1-lts #1 SMP Thu, 15 Sep 2022 09:53:50 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've installed the MS Teams Linux app, but I also tried the Edge, Chromium and Firefox variant. But i'm not able to share my whole screen, only "some" apps not even all...
I found some issues related the electron version of teams with Wayland, but with the browser versions that should not happen... but it does.

I also deactivated the wayland session, but then my whole desktop starts to behave strange... Anyone with some ideas? Need more infos?

Thanks and bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of Teams. Here is a community feedback post to Microsoft regarding the issue: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/4eacaa70-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2

Note that some users have success switching over to X11 when needing to screen share.

Comment: because of some other issues with linux as workstation in a windows environment, I changed my OS back to windows.... now I can collaborate.
But I still will use Linux Manjaro in a VM :-)

Comment: I fully understand the sentiment. I use Linux at work, but have a Windows box that I have laying around just in case. Things are better than they used to be at least.

Comment: Atleast at xfce and kde it seems to be solved in the meanwhile..
I tried it in a virtualbox and a colleague of mine installed manjaro with kde on his laptop. It seems like everything works like intended.... lets see